# Last_sign_in value not updated for ACC, only BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

When testing the endpoint for GET Users found here:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-:user_id-GET/

The value for "last_sign_in" is not updated when the user logs into the ACC (acc.autodesk.com), nor any ACC projects. The value IS updated when accessing a BIM 360 project.

As I understand it, the value for "last_sign_in" in the report "admin_users.csv" from the Data Connector also does not report the logins for ACC projects.

The documentation states that the endpoint is compatible with both BIM 360 and ACC projects. Should the value at this endpoint be expected to update, or should Activities be used to determine when a user last accessed the platform?

Comment: As I remember, there is a limitation with ACC  last sign in. Let me double check and get back to you

Comment: I can reproduce this problem and am checking with engineer team

Comment: After discussing with engineer team, I got to know We don't track last sign in for ACC apps right now, but that's something we'd like to do in the future. So I finally logged this issue with internal ticket: ACSAPI-879. Sorry for the issue and thank you for your patience

Comment: @XiaodongLiang thank you for checking with the engineering team. It would be helpful to clarify in the BIM 360 API documentation that although the endpoint is compatible with the ACC, the last_sign_in field is only accurate for BIM 360 projects. Thanks again!

Comment: good suggestion! I will ask team to do. Thank you for your understanding